# Cannot resize videos using moviepy on aws lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, moviepy

I partially created an aws lambda function that utilize moviepy to concatenate images and videos in a single video file.

For example, I have “img1.jpeg”, “img2.jpeg”, “video1.mp4” and “video2.mp4”. After processing the above files the final clip (“mp4” file) will be a single mp4 file of: “img1.jpeg + video1.mp4 + img2.jpeg + video2.mp4”. The fresulted clip resolution is 640x480.

So I resize the videos and the images (moviepy.video.fx.all.resize - resize images after converting to videos) in the case that they are greater than the aforementioned resolution. If the media files are in the above size, I move to the concatenation process.

When the media files are 640x480 all the process goes fine. The issue is when the media are larger than 640x480 I get an error:

```
[Errno 32] Broken pipe

MoviePy error: FFMPEG encountered the following error while writing file 1_img_transTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3:

1_img_transTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3: Permission denied


The audio export failed, possily because the bitrate you specified was two high or too low for the video codec.: IOError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/media_merge.py", line 70, in handler
s.do_merge()
File "/var/task/mediamerge/stitch_video_and_images.py", line 320, in do_merge
self.convert_crop_media()
File "/var/task/mediamerge/stitch_video_and_images.py", line 310, in convert_crop_media
res_path = resize.resize_media()
File "/var/task/mediamerge/stitch_video_and_images.py", line 229, in resize_media
self.final_media_file, verbose=False)
File "<decorator-gen-51>", line 2, in write_videofile
File "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
return f(clip, *a, **k)
File "<decorator-gen-50>", line 2, in write_videofile
File "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 137, in use_clip_fps_by_default
return f(clip, *new_a, **new_kw)
File "<decorator-gen-49>", line 2, in write_videofile
File "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 22, in convert_masks_to_RGB
return f(clip, *a, **k)
File "/var/task/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 331, in write_videofile
verbose=verbose)
File "<decorator-gen-73>", line 2, in write_audiofile
File "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
return f(clip, *a, **k)
File "/var/task/moviepy/audio/AudioClip.py", line 204, in write_audiofile
verbose=verbose, ffmpeg_params=ffmpeg_params)
File "<decorator-gen-70>", line 2, in ffmpeg_audiowrite
File "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
return f(clip, *a, **k)
File "/var/task/moviepy/audio/io/ffmpeg_audiowriter.py", line 162, in ffmpeg_audiowrite
writer.write_frames(chunk)
File "/var/task/moviepy/audio/io/ffmpeg_audiowriter.py", line 122, in write_frames
raise IOError(error)
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

MoviePy error: FFMPEG encountered the following error while writing file 1_img_transTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3:

1_img_transTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3: Permission denied


The audio export failed, possily because the bitrate you specified was two high or too low for the video codec.
```

The above is from aws lambda logs. The funny thing is, that when I ran it locally it works.

Has anyone ever faced a similar issue or is anyone able to give me some pointers on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: By the way, ignore the last line about the audio bitrate. It is just a generic comment.

Answer (score 0):

With lambda file permissions can be funny. Use /tmp for any temp, working files etc.

Not sure if that will help but good to know.

```
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
LIB_DIR = os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, 'lib')



lambda_tmp_dir = '/tmp' # Lambda fuction can use this directory.
image_path = "{0}/{1}".format(lambda_tmp_dir, "images")
video_path = "{0}/{1}".format(lambda_tmp_dir, "video")
video_name = "video.mp4"

# ffmpeg is stored with this script.
# When executing ffmpeg, execute permission is requierd.
# But Lambda source directory do not have permission to change it.
# So move ffmpeg binary to `/tmp` and add permission.
FFMPEG_BINARY = "{0}/ffmpeg".format(lambda_tmp_dir)
shutil.copyfile('/var/task/ffmpeg/ffmpeg', FFMPEG_BINARY)
FFPROBE_BINARY = "{0}/ffprobe".format(lambda_tmp_dir)
shutil.copyfile('/var/task/ffmpeg/ffprobe', FFPROBE_BINARY)

os.environ['FFPROBE'] = FFPROBE_BINARY
os.environ['FFMPEG'] = FFMPEG_BINARY
os.chmod(FFPROBE_BINARY, os.stat(FFPROBE_BINARY).st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)
os.chmod(FFMPEG_BINARY, os.stat(FFMPEG_BINARY).st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import uuid
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

from moviepy.config import change_settings

import os
from shutil import copyfile
import stat

lambda_tmp_dir = '/tmp'
FFMPEG_BINARY = "{0}/ffmpeg".format(lambda_tmp_dir)
change_settings({"FFMPEG_BINARY": FFMPEG_BINARY})
copyfile('/var/task/ffmpeg', FFMPEG_BINARY)
FFPROBE_BINARY = "{0}/ffprobe".format(lambda_tmp_dir)
copyfile('/var/task/ffprobe', FFPROBE_BINARY)
os.environ['FFPROBE'] = FFPROBE_BINARY
os.environ['FFMPEG'] = FFMPEG_BINARY
os.chmod(FFPROBE_BINARY, os.stat(FFPROBE_BINARY).st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)
os.chmod(FFMPEG_BINARY, os.stat(FFMPEG_BINARY).st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
    from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        print('{} - {}'.format(bucket, key))
        key_without_path = key.replace('/', '')
        source_file = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key_without_path)
        try:
            s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, source_file)
        except ClientError as e:
            if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
                return None
        try:
            short_clip_path = '/tmp/resized{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key_without_path)
            ffmpeg_extract_subclip(source_file, 2, 5, targetname=short_clip_path)
            clip = VideoFileClip(source_file)
            print('clip.duration = {}'.format(clip.duration))
            clip.save_frame("{}.jpg".format(short_clip_path), t=4.00)

            if clip.duration > 5:
                print('clip bigger then 5')
        except:
            return None
        s3_client.upload_file(short_clip_path, bucket.replace('-', '-thumb-'), key)
        s3_client.upload_file("{}.jpg".format(short_clip_path), bucket.replace('-', '-thumb-'), "{}.jpg".format(key))
```

Download 64 bit static and unzip it and add 2 files to the lambda zip
https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/